# Why is the range not $(-\infty,+\infty)$ for $G(t)=\frac{5}{t^2-9}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> I am trying to find the range of $$G(t)= \frac{5}{t^2-9}.$$

I understand the range to be all possible outputs that the function can have. When I imput this problem to symbolab, I find that the range is $(-\infty,-5/9] \cup (0,+\infty)$. I am very confused as to why the range is limited to these values and is not $(-\infty,+\infty)$. Why is it limited to those values? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Find a value of $t$ for which $G(t)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$y = \frac{5}{t^2-9}\implies t^2 = \frac{5}{y} +9 \ge 0 \implies \frac{5}{y} \ge -9. $$
Now, if $y > 0$ then obviously $\frac{5}{y} \ge -9$. For $y < 0$, we have
$$\frac{5}{y} \ge -9 \implies y \le -\frac{5}{9}.$$
So the range is
$$(-\infty,-5/9] \cup (0,+\infty).$$

Comment: I think your work shows that the range is a subset of $(-\infty,-5/9] \cup (0,+\infty)$. Don't we have to do a little more work to show that it is actually equal to that set?

Comment: The range is the domain of $\sqrt{\frac{5}{y}+9}$, which is all the values of y such that $\frac{5}{y}+9\ge0$, and $y \neq 0$.

Comment: You should specify that $y > 0$ rather than $y \geq 0$ in your second sentence.

Answer (score 0):

$t^2-9$ can never be less than $-9$. So $5/(t^2-9)$ cannot lie between
$-5/9$ and $0$ for that would make $t^2-9<-9$.

Answer (score 0):

If $5/(t^2-9)=c$ then $t^2=(5+9c)/c$ must be non-negative. That’s the case iff $c$ is not  between $-5/9$ and zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the function equal to $0$, then when you multiply both sides by $t^2-9$ you get $5=0$.  This shows that there is no value of $t$ that makes the expression equal to zero.

I think the best way to find the range is to graph the function and then look for horizontal lines that don't intersect the graph.  In this case, the horizontal line $y=0$ misses the graph.   If a horizontal line $y=a$ hits the graph, you just have to look at the $t$-coordinate of that point to find a value of $t$ that gives $G(t) =a$.

The graph of this function has three pieces.  Two are sort of hyperbola-shaped piece above the $t$-axis.  The other is an infinite hotdog that has $y$-intercept at $-5/9$ and stretches down to $-\infty.$  The gap in the $y$-direction between $-5/9$ and $0$ shows that this little interval is not in the range.

Answer (score 0):

If the function $G$ is surjective then for all $k \in \mathbb{R}$ there exist a $x_k$ such that :

$$\frac{5}{x_k^2-9}=k$$

So $x_k$ has to be a root of the second order polynomial :
$$kx^2-9k-5$$

Which means :

$$x_{k\ne 0}^2 = 9-\frac{5}{k} \geq 0$$

Can you conclude from here ? (don’t forget the fact that $G$ is not defined at $\pm 3$).